# Mongo shell not found or not installed

Tags: mongodb, installation

Mongo shell not found or not installed

I installed mongodb using

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

The installation was successful, I did the RHEL port config required, and I started the mongod service.

```
[root@host mongodb]# service mongod status
mongod (pid 1761) is running...
```

However, when I look for the mongo shell, I cannot find it using the 'locate' command:

```
locate mongo
/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.0.repo
/usr/share/vim/vim72/keymap/mongolian_utf-8.vim
/var/mongodb
```

According to the mongo docs, this is how you start the shell:
To start the mongo shell and connect to your MongoDB instance running on localhost with default port:

1. Go to your : cd
2. Type ./bin/mongo to start mongo: ./bin/mongo

**Questions**:

1. What is the {mongodb installation dir}? /var/mongodb does not have any contents
2. Is there something wrong with the installation of the mongo shell? Install contents below.

sudo yum install -y mongodb-org

```
            Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
            Determining fastest mirrors
             * base: centos.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net
             * extras: centos.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net
             * updates: centos.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net
            base                                                                                                           | 3.7 kB     00:00
            base/primary_db                                                                                                | 4.6 MB     00:02
            extras                                                                                                         | 3.4 kB     00:00
            extras/primary_db                                                                                              |  27 kB     00:00
            mongodb-org-3.0                                                                                                |  951 B     00:00
            mongodb-org-3.0/primary                                                                                        | 8.6 kB     00:00
            mongodb-org-3.0                                                                                                                 45/45
            updates                                                                                                        | 3.4 kB     00:00
            updates/primary_db                                                                                             | 1.3 MB     00:00
            Setting up Install Process
            Resolving Dependencies
            --> Running transaction check
            ---> Package mongodb-org.x86_64 0:3.0.6-1.el6 will be installed
            --> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-shell = 3.0.6 for package: mongodb-org-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64
            --> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-tools = 3.0.6 for package: mongodb-org-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64
            --> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-server = 3.0.6 for package: mongodb-org-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64
            --> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-mongos = 3.0.6 for package: mongodb-org-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64
            --> Running transaction check
            ---> Package mongodb-org-mongos.x86_64 0:3.0.6-1.el6 will be installed
            ---> Package mongodb-org-server.x86_64 0:3.0.6-1.el6 will be installed
            ---> Package mongodb-org-shell.x86_64 0:3.0.6-1.el6 will be installed
            ---> Package mongodb-org-tools.x86_64 0:3.0.6-1.el6 will be installed
            --> Finished Dependency Resolution

            Dependencies Resolved

            ======================================================================================================================================
             Package                              Arch                     Version                        Repository                         Size
            ======================================================================================================================================
            Installing:
             mongodb-org                          x86_64                   3.0.6-1.el6                    mongodb-org-3.0                   4.6 k
            Installing for dependencies:
             mongodb-org-mongos                   x86_64                   3.0.6-1.el6                    mongodb-org-3.0                   3.9 M
             mongodb-org-server                   x86_64                   3.0.6-1.el6                    mongodb-org-3.0                   8.3 M
             mongodb-org-shell                    x86_64                   3.0.6-1.el6                    mongodb-org-3.0                   4.1 M
             mongodb-org-tools                    x86_64                   3.0.6-1.el6                    mongodb-org-3.0                    31 M

            Transaction Summary
            ======================================================================================================================================
            Install       5 Package(s)

            Total download size: 48 M
            Installed size: 149 M
            Downloading Packages:
            (1/5): mongodb-org-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                      | 4.6 kB     00:00
            (2/5): mongodb-org-mongos-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                               | 3.9 MB     00:03
            (3/5): mongodb-org-server-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                               | 8.3 MB     00:04
            (4/5): mongodb-org-shell-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                | 4.1 MB     00:04
            (5/5): mongodb-org-tools-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                |  31 MB     00:05
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Total                                                                                                 2.4 MB/s |  48 MB     00:20
            Running rpm_check_debug
            Running Transaction Test
            Transaction Test Succeeded
            Running Transaction
              Installing : mongodb-org-server-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64                                                                              1/5
              Installing : mongodb-org-shell-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64                                                                               2/5
              Installing : mongodb-org-mongos-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64                                                                              3/5
              Installing : mongodb-org-tools-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64                                                                               4/5
              Installing : mongodb-org-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                     5/5
              Verifying  : mongodb-org-tools-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64                                                                               1/5
              Verifying  : mongodb-org-mongos-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64                                                                              2/5
              Verifying  : mongodb-org-shell-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64                                                                               3/5
              Verifying  : mongodb-org-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                     4/5
              Verifying  : mongodb-org-server-3.0.6-1.el6.x86_64                                                                              5/5

            Installed:
              mongodb-org.x86_64 0:3.0.6-1.el6

            Dependency Installed:
              mongodb-org-mongos.x86_64 0:3.0.6-1.el6     mongodb-org-server.x86_64 0:3.0.6-1.el6     mongodb-org-shell.x86_64 0:3.0.6-1.el6
              mongodb-org-tools.x86_64 0:3.0.6-1.el6


            Complete!
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about software development as defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You might get better advise on https://unix.stackexchange.com, though.

Comment: I've answered, but I will be voting to close this out too, as mentioned, it belongs on other StackExchange sites (ServerFault or Unix)

Answer (score 0):

It is installed as part of the mongodb-org-shell package (which you have installed) and here's how you figure it out:

```
[root@centos6 ~]# rpm -ql mongodb-org-shell-3.0.6-1
package mongodb-org-shell-3.0.6-1 is not installed
[root@centos6 ~]# rpm -ql mongodb-org-shell-3.0.6-1.el6
/usr/bin/mongo
/usr/share/man/man1/mongo.1
[root@centos6 ~]# ls -lah /usr/bin/mongo
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 11M Aug 24 13:19 /usr/bin/mongo
```

So, it is in `/usr/bin`.  If you are getting a not found error I suspect that `/usr/bin` is not in your path (which would be odd) or you have some strange permissions issue.